# Backbone.JS single page app support for bulk print

Tags: backbone.js, printing, pdf-generation

How can I implement "bulk print" in a Single Page application built using Backbone.JS?

Are the techniques similar to adding support for Search Engine to crawl SPA webapp?

Comment: Yes, I think so. You can use Phantom JS to print the state of your application based on the route/url. There are also commercial options available. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php